# Order of Growth of Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

Following question, which was asked in **GRE computer science test 2001**.

Q-67: Consider the following **C code**.

```
int f(int x) {
    if(x<1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return f(x-1)+g(x);
    }
}

int g(int x) {
    if(x<2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return f(x-1)+g(x/2);
    }   
}
```

Of the following, which best describes the **growth** of **f(x)** as a function of **x**?

(A) **Logarithmic**
(B) **Linear**
(C) **Quadratic**
(D) **Cubic**
(E) **Exponential**

By the way, **correct answer** is **(E)** Exponential (mentioned in its answer key). But, I don't know the exact method for solving that.

Could anybody solve above **recurrence relations**? Do you have any **alternative approach**?

Please share your views.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be simplified as
`f(x) >= f(x-1)+f(x-1) for x>1`,
because `g(x) = f(x-1)+g(x/2) >= f(x-1) for x>1`.
The first inequality is just `f(x) >= 2*f(x-1)`, and from here it's easy to derive that `f(x) >= 2^x*f(1)` (value of `f` at least doubles every time `x` grows by 1).

Comment: Thanks @Inspired. Considering all the conditions, final recurrence relations would be as following:

Comment: Thanks @Inspired. Considering all the conditions, final recurrence relations would be as following: f(x)=1 when x<1; f(x)=f(x-1)+1 when x=1; f(x)=2*f(x-1)+g(x/2) when x>1.

Comment: Only important relation to the growth of f(x) is f(x)=2*f(x-1)+g(x/2) when x>1. Calculating order of growth by parts, we would get O(2^x) for the first part: 2*f(x-1), but what about second part: g(x/2) ?

Comment: I guess `g(x/2)` will give us something about `f(x/2) + f(x/4) + f(x/8) + ...` which is superseded by `2*f(x/2)` (as we know that `f` grows much faster than a linear function, and for a linear function the upper bound would be `2*f(x/2)`). So the final growth is a bit higher than O(2^x), but lower than O(2^x + sqrt(2^x)) which looks still exponential to me.
In fact, as we already know from the first part analysis that `f(x)` grows at least exponentially, and as `g(x) >= 0`, we can answer the original question even without g(x/2) analysis (there are no other possible options in the question).

Comment: Nice explanation